# Apache Poi WORD Paragraph with image and text

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

i am trying to create a paragraph using APACHE POI,that contains an image on the left and some text on the right. Is there any way that i can set alignment between these two components?

Below is the code that does what i want in a table, but it also renders the two paragraphs.

```
public void createWord() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
      XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("createdocument.docx"));
      File img = new File("C:\\Users\\r4rfgretg\\Pictures\\geregrg.png");
        XWPFParagraph imageParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        imageParagraph.setFontAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER.getValue());
        XWPFRun imageRun = imageParagraph.createRun();
        imageRun.addBreak();
        imageRun.addBreak();
        imageRun.addBreak();

        imageRun.addPicture(new FileInputStream(img), org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "test",
                Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(100));

        XWPFParagraph textParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun textRun = textParagraph.createRun();
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.addBreak();
        imageRun.addBreak();
        imageRun.addBreak();
        imageRun.addBreak();
        textRun.setText("KOU323D342342OUMjuj43432424S");
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.setText("1/1/2019                           1/1/2020");
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.addBreak();
        textRun.setText("GR123456789");

      XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
      tableRowOne.getCell(0).setParagraph(imageParagraph);
      tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setParagraph(textParagraph);

    document.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("createdocument.docx written successully");

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Main problem with your code is that it creates the `XWPFParagraph`s in the `XWPFDocument` first and then it sets them into the `XWPFTableCell`s. But a `XWPFTableCell` contains it's own body and is able containing content of a whole document also. So after that the paragraph is in the documents body and in the table cells body. So don't do this. Instead get `XWPFParagraph`s from or create `XWPFParagraph`s in the `XWPFTableCell`s if needed.

In general your requirement "an image on the left and some text on the right" can be fulfilled two ways. It can be fulfilled using a table, as you tried. But it can also be fulfilled using only one paragraph, as you told in your question's title. This paragraph must contain tab stop settings then and the runs must be split by tabulators.

The following code shows both solutions:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTabStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTabJc;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTblWidth;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblWidth;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTabulatorAndTable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String text = "Text";
  String imgFile="Koala.png";
  int twipsPerInch = 1440; //measurement unit for table cell width and tab stop pos is twips (twentieth of an inch point)

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Image on the left and text on the right");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("First using a table:");

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  table.setWidth(6*twipsPerInch);
  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 2 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column = 2 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*twipsPerInch));
  //second column = 4 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4*twipsPerInch));
  //create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.getRow(0);
  //first cell
  XWPFTableCell cell = tableRow.getCell(0);
  //set width for first column = 2 inches
  CTTblWidth tblWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
  tblWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2*twipsPerInch));
  //STTblWidth.DXA is used to specify width in twentieths of a point.
  tblWidth.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
  //first paragraph in first cell
  paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0); if (paragraph == null) paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
  //first run in paragraph having picture
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(100));
  //second cell
  cell = tableRow.addNewTableCell();
  cell.setText(text);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Second using tabulator having tab stops:");

  //create tab stop at 2 inches position
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
  CTTabStop tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().addNewTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getTabs().addNewTab();
  tabStop.setVal(STTabJc.LEFT);
  tabStop.setPos(BigInteger.valueOf(2 * twipsPerInch));
  //first run in paragraph having picture
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(100), Units.toEMU(100));
  run.addTab();
  //second run 
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(text);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTabulatorAndTable.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]